# Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Fruits[]' to 'Fruits' (CS0029) (Assembly-CSharp)

Tags: unity

I'm having an error produced when I compile my Unity game:

> Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Fruits[]' to 'Fruits' (CS0029) (Assembly-CSharp)

It's coming from the line:

```
f = Instantiate (fruitPrefab).GetComponents<Fruits>();
```

Why do I have this error and how can I resolve it?

Here is the rest of the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {
  private const float REQUIED_SLICEFORCE=400.0f;
  private List<Fruits> fruties = new List<Fruits> ();
  public GameObject fruitPrefab;
  private float lastSpawn;
  private float deltaSpawn=2.0f;
  public Transform trail;
  private Collider2D[] fruitCols;
  private Vector3 lastmousepos;

  // Use this for initialization
  private void Start () {
    fruitCols=new Collider2D[0];
  }

  private Fruits GetFruits ()
  {
    Fruits f = fruties.Find (x=>!x.IsActive);
    if (f==null) 
    {
      f = Instantiate (fruitPrefab).GetComponents<Fruits>();    

      fruties.Add (f);
    }
    return f;
  }
}
```

Comment: is there any solution for this error?

Comment: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'Fruits[]' to 'Fruits' ` -- C# is telling you it can't convert something that is a `Fruits[]` array (GetComponents returns an array) to a `Fruits` object. (`f` is a `Fruits` object)

Comment: You could try `GetComponent` (singular) if you expect only one component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the official [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponents.html), `GetComponents<T>` will return `T[]`, or in your case, `Fruits[]`.

You probably want to use `GetComponent<T>` instead that will return a single `Fruit`, which is the same type of your `f` variable.